# root (a-asin(x) = cos(x) ? or what?

Tags: trigonometry

Can you explain whats going on here? is it some trig identity i dont know or something else?

[image]

Comment: You're getting a lot of downvotes because you haven't supplied us with an attempt on your part.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factor $R^2$ and note that

> $$1- \sin ^2 (x) = \cos ^2 (x).$$

Comment: but if i put (5-5sin(90))^0.5 in a calculator is not the same as 5 (1-1sin(90))^0.5

Comment: is the 5-5sin(90) not the two terms?

Comment: @tgmjack $\sqrt{5-5\sin^2(90^\circ)} = \sqrt{5(1-\sin^2(90^\circ))}$

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

$
\sqrt{R^2-R^2(\sin\theta)^2} = \sqrt{R^2(1-\sin^2 \theta)}
$

And because

$
1-\sin^2 (\theta) = \cos^2 (\theta)
$

You can get

$
\sqrt{R^2\cos^2 (\theta)} = R\cos(\theta)
$

Comment: yeah but it equals 2R^2*cos^2(x)    not      2√R^2*cos^2(x) 

where does the root go?

if the power cancels the roots

Comment: the root cancels the powers